# Volley, SwipeToRefresh and notifyDataSetChanged() not working

Tags: android

I fetch the data from my Server with Volley and put the data inside a GridView.

Now when I use swipeToRefresh, it should load the new/changed data. For this I tried everything but nothing worked.

First my code:

MainActivity.java

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<getter_setter> list = new ArrayList<>();
    grid_adapter grid_adapter;
    GridView gridView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);


        getData();
        gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        grid_adapter = new grid_adapter(getApplicationContext(),list);
        gridView.setAdapter(grid_adapter);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                        getData();
                        grid_adapter.update(list);

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });





    }

    public void getData(){
        final String url = "http://*.**.***.***/";
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("userdata");
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String NAME = jsonObject.getString("NAME");
                        String BILD = jsonObject.getString("VORSCHAUBILD");

                        getter_setter getter_setter = new getter_setter(NAME,"",BILD);
                        list.add(getter_setter);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

And the BaseAdapter

```js
public class grid_adapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    List<getter_setter> list;

    public grid_adapter(Context context, List<getter_setter> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    public void update(List<getter_setter> listUpdate){
       this.list.addAll(listUpdate);
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View gridView = view;
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_design,null);
        }

        final getter_setter getter = list.get(i);

        TextView name = gridView.findViewById(R.id.NAME);
        final ImageView bild = gridView.findViewById(R.id.bild);

        name.setText(getter.getNAME());
        Picasso.with(context).load(getter.getVORSCHAUBILD()).into(bild);

        return gridView;
    }
}
```

Comment: provide your xml

Comment: which xml do you mean?

Comment: tell me one thing is your listview is under the swipe refresh layout?

Comment: I don't have a listview, I'm using gridview as you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check The Updated Listener

**Explanation-:**
   Since You Are Passing Reference Of Your List Into RecyclerView Hence Updating List In The Activity Will Update The List In Adapter Automatically

> No Need To Call update Method

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                            list.clear(); // Clean The List Before Adding Updated Data
                            grid_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            getData();
                            grid_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Debug If Data Is being recieved When request is complete